# What is the difference between following statements

Tags: c

What is the difference between following 2 scanf statements,

```
#include<stdio.h>  
void main()  
{  
    int a,b;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n Enter values for a and b");
    scanf("%d",&a); // Format specifier as %d
    scanf("%i",&b); // Format specifier as %i
    printf("\n a is %d and b is %i",a,b);
    getch();
}
```

I given values a as 10 and b as 20. It is giving same values as an output,
So my questions are
what is the difference between %d and %i.??
What about the memory for each variable ??
Is there is any difference between %d and %i as a format specifier ???

Comment: Did you even try Google?

Comment: Ya of course,i think it is not so much perfect....!!!!

Comment: You don't think google knows the answer? What is your comment trying to commune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). For convenience, `%i` (integer) as a placeholder means:

> Any number of digits, optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -).
>   Decimal digits assumed by default (0-9), but a 0 prefix introduces octal digits (0-7), and 0x hexadecimal digits (0-f).

... and `%d` (decimal integer) means:

> Any number of decimal digits (0-9), optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -).

Comment: No. That is _not_ what % means. % means the next character or few are a format specifier.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson, ... a typographical error for `%d`. It is fixed. For the down votes, those are entirely unnecessary -- I have communicated the answer to the question so I would appreciate if they are removed. Regardless of whether the question is "good" or not.

Comment: What about the memory required...???

Comment: I downvoted evaluate the blurb on % was wrong. I've removed it now. As for the others, I don't know

Comment: @Vaibhav what do you mean?

Comment: @Vaibhav, an integer. I'll edit my post to include that detail. The resource I provided you with has more than enough information, please refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

See the output of "man scanf".

```
   d      Matches  an  optionally signed decimal integer; the next pointer
          must be a pointer to int.
```

...

```
   i      Matches an optionally signed integer; the next pointer must be a
          pointer  to  int.   The  integer is read in base 16 if it begins
          with 0x or 0X, in base 8 if it begins with 0,  and  in  base  10
          otherwise.   Only  characters  that  correspond  to the base are
          used.
```

That means: %d just read an signed decimal integer. %i read an signed integer, decimal/oct/hex depends on your input. It begins with 0x or 0X is hex, begins 0 is oct, others are decimal.